# SocketTimeoutException on getting data from inputstream in tomcat

Tags: performance, tomcat, servlets, load-balancing, tomcat8

I am getting sockettimeeout exception on reading data from inputstream

source code

```
public void clientData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
            InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
            String body = null;
            body = IOUtils.toString(in);
}
```

```
 org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException|
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:348)|
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:663)|
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:370)|
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)|
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)|
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)|
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)|
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)|
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1680)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1659)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1636)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1583)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1608)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:668)|
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:646)|
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException|
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:201)|
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235)|
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216)|
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1282)|
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1225)|
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:737)|
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:42)|
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1120)|
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)|
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:262)|
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)|
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:344)|
    ... 59 more|
```

server.xml is with below configurations

connectionTimeout="20000" maxThread="150"

There are thousands of client concurrently accessing tomcat server

Note:
Not able to reproduce the above case, Sometimes this exception occurs

Exception occurred after reaching 20seconds (connectionTimeout) in server.xml

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes it's bandwidth issue, So reduced amount of request data size from client  @Jasir

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue, Issue is due to bandwidth between client and server. When we reduce the amount of traffic(request data size reduced) between client and server

It's working without an issue